# Izpack force minimum JRE

Tags: installation, java-8, javafx-8, izpack

I'm developing a Java application which uses JavaFx8 APIs , and I wrote an IZpack installer for it.When I already have JRE8 on my pc it works great. I know that it will not work when the user has a JRE which is less that JRE8. First , how can I check if the user has JRE8 or not? and how can I prompt a message that tells the user to install JRE8 if he hasn't?

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce the minimum Java version for the installer by using the `javaversion` tag in your install file:

```
<javaversion>1.8.0</javaversion>
```

To prompt the user to install a matching JRE I recommend the [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) project. If you are using maven as a build tool this code example may help you to get started:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.bluestemsoftware.open.maven.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>launch4j-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>l4j-gui</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>launch4j</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <headerType>gui</headerType>
          <outfile>${project.build.directory}/xxx-Setup.exe</outfile>
          <jar>${project.build.directory}/xxx-Setup.jar</jar>
          <jre>
            <path>src/jre8</path>
            <minVersion>1.8.0</minVersion>
          </jre>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```